# Is there a program to charge/discharge the battery automatically without the need to unplug the ac adapter everytime?

Tags: software-recommendation, battery, acpi

I want to give some life to my old laptop, and recalibrate the battery (old now).
When reading around on forums, the common info is to turn on the PC, drain the batt, even from Bios, and then recharge batt without having the PC on, and repeat cycle until satisfied.
I hope there is a way to soft up this via ACPI without the need to actually let the PC die out of misery.
I was hoping for a program that when running, shall unlink the actual AC power source from the Battery charging mechanism.

So when program is running, even if the laptop is plugged, it shall use the power from Battery until fully drained, then, once drained, it starts recharging. All this without shutting down the PC when no power from battery.

I have checked all around, and the only softwares found are actually fancy readers for the Bat0/Info data or behaviour modifier for the rest of the PC.

Has any of you ever heard of a software doing this?

Comment: FYI, you generally only need to do it once, repeating won't help if you did it right the first time.  Start with a 100% full battery, run to dead, recharge to full, done.

Comment: Li-Ion batteries don't actually need the full-drain calibration that older NiCad batteries did. For longevity, it's actually better to keep the battery above 60-80%. A full charge cycle once a month or so is recommended, but only so that any OS metering gets reset and realigned.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, the choice of power source it is automatically controlled by the bios, may also be the case that this is done by the motherboard hardware itself. I seriously doubt that there is an option to change this.